# Replacing a JavaScript function with a UserStyle

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I'm working on modifying a UserStyle for Instapaper.  Since the original UserStyle was written, Instapaper added to their header a number of JavaScript functions that control the width of the page and the typefaces used.

Here they are:

```
        function loadDefaults()
        {
            _fontSize = 16;
            _fontFamily = "G";
            _lineHeight = 1.5;
            _width = 500;
        }

        function loadFont()
        {
            var cookieData = readCookie("fontMetrics");
            if (cookieData && (cookieData = cookieData.split("_")) && cookieData.length == 4) {
                _fontSize = parseInt(cookieData[0]);
                _fontFamily = cookieData[1];
                _lineHeight = parseFloat(cookieData[2]);
                _width = parseInt(cookieData[3]);
            } else loadDefaults();

            applyFont();
        }
```

How would I go about modifying the UserScript to override these functions, since they execute after load?

So far, I've tried simply replacing these functions with blank overrides, but it didn't work.  Since my script executes first, is there some way I can just remove the entire JavaScript block in the header?

Comment: Where do you get in InstaPaper a UserStyle to modify. In Account settings I don't see any possibility to modify a user style.

Comment: I'm using Fluid.app and the Instapaper Threestyled Narrow script from http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73567

Answer (score 1):

First of all, userscripts are for javascript not userstyles.  Secondly you want to use [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) in your user script in order to overwrite functions defined in the `window` scope by the webpage.

So your code would look like:

```
    unsafeWindow.loadDefaults = function loadDefaults()
    {
        _fontSize = 16;
        _fontFamily = "G";
        _lineHeight = 1.5;
        _width = 500;
    }

    unsafeWindow.loadFont = function loadFont()
    {
        var cookieData = readCookie("fontMetrics");
        if (cookieData && (cookieData = cookieData.split("_")) && cookieData.length == 4) {
            _fontSize = parseInt(cookieData[0]);
            _fontFamily = cookieData[1];
            _lineHeight = parseFloat(cookieData[2]);
            _width = parseInt(cookieData[3]);
        } else loadDefaults();

        applyFont();
    }
```